# using function wheen looping through dataframe python/pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that uses two colomns in a dataframe:

```
def create_time(var, var1):  
    if var == "Helår":  
        y = var1+'Q4'  
    else:  
        if var == 'Halvår':  
            y = var1+'Q2'  
        else:  
            y = var1+'Q'+str(var)[0:1]  
    return y
```

Now i want to loop hrough my dataframe, creatring a new column using the function, where var  and var1 are columns in the dataframe

I try with the following, but have no luck:

```
for row in bd.iterrows():
      A = str(bd['Var'])    
      B = str(bd['Var1'])
      bd['period']=create_time(A,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping is a last resort. There is usually a "vectorized" way to operate on the entire DataFrame, which always faster and usually more readable too.

To apply your custom function to each row, use `apply` with the keyword argument `axis=1`.

```
bd['period'] = bd[['Var', 'Var1']].apply(lambda x: create_time(*x), axis=1)
```

You might wonder why it's not just `bd.apply(create_time)`. Since `create_time` wants two arguments, we have to "unpack" the row `x` into its two values and pass those to the function.

Comment: Thanks. I just have the problem that there is more than just var and var 1 in the datafram. Hwo do you solve this?   Tried this without luck   bd['period'] = bd.apply(lambda x: create_time(x['Var'],x['Var1'], axis=1))

Comment: Just want to mention that it works perfect on a df with only the right columns....